# HTML Injection in angular 13

Tags: html, angular, forms

```
<form #userform="ngForm">
  <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username" #userName="ngModel" required   
            (focus)="removeErrorMsg()">
</form>
```

Using an input element inside angular form tag, in the UI i was able to enter the following HTML in the username field :

`<b>HTML INJECTION</b><img src=images/some-custom-image-url>`

Sending the req to backend while clicking on Save Button.

I can see this to be injected in Input element.

I researched a lot about how to prevent this, but not able to find any solution to this.Since Angular itself takes care of this with DOM Sanitization. But here it does not.

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: You can't prevent HTML input in form tag (unless you try impossible regex). But you must always encode user input before outputting it.

Comment: Didn't got your second part. how to encode ?

Comment: E.g. in php: `echo htmlentities($userInput);` -> will output HTML as plain text and not actual parsed HTML

Comment: What does "I can see this to be injected in Input element" mean?
It obviously doesn't show the html formatting, just the string, right?